# When do new buildings from research appear?

Tags: kittens-game

I've researched Mathematics and the description says:

> Allows construction of Academies, very efficient research buildings

However, a season has now passed and the building still doesn't appear for construction at my bonfire. After researching Animal Husbandry the pastures didn't appear instantly either, but were there when I checked back a few minutes later.

I've also researched Mining but there are no mines available to build.

Are there any other requirements for the buildings to appear or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the code, in buildings.js, there is the following:

```
var res = this.game.resPool.get(price.name);
if (res.value < price.val * unlockRatio){
    isEnabled = false;
    break;
}
```

Thus, to unlock a building, you need at least `unlockRatio` of each resource that is used in building it. The default is to require 30% of the cost of a building, with only one building having a non-default value.

> For those looking to know, the [religion-related Ziggurat](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Religion) is the one with non-default unlockRatio. It's set to 5%, partly so you don't need a ton of Megaliths before you ever know what they're good for; building a handful to see if they do anything is generally enough.

Building your first Academy will cost 50 Wood, 70 Minerals, and 100 Science, so you should only need 15 Wood, 21 Minerals, and 30 Science to unlock them. Mines should unlock once you have 30 Wood, and Pastures would have appeared once you had 30 Catnip and 3 Wood.

Comment: The building does only unlock if you actually have that amount of materials, or the storage size?

Comment: @Mathias711 You have to have the actual amount. I tried it and the buildings really appear as soon as you have 30% of all actual resources required.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Another reason to gather as much as possible of resources